# Wrapping an operator[ ] of a private container in derived class

Tags: c++, function, derived-class

I am trying to implement a wrapping function named: `Shape& move_up(int index)`, that will access and modify<sup>1</sup> elements of `vector<T*> v`, in the derived class, named: `class Group`.

I am trying to do that by  wrapping the `T& operator[](int i) { return *v[i]; }` of the base class:

`Group.h`:

```
// class Group is a container of Shapes
class Group: public Graph_lib::Vector_ref<Shape>{
public:
    // constructors
    Group::Group()  
     : upperLeft(0, 0), gridSideX(50), gridSideY(50), gridRowNumber(5), gridColumnNumber(5) 
    {
     // create grid
     for (size_t i = 0; i <= gridRowNumber; ++i){ 
         for (size_t j = 0; j <= gridColumnNumber; ++j){
              Graph_lib::Rectangle* rec = new Graph_lib::Rectangle(Point(upperLeft.x + gridSideX * j, upperLeft.y + gridSideY * i), gridSideX, gridSideY);
              rec->set_fill_color(((i + j) % 2 == 0) ? Color::black : Color::white); 
              push_back(rec);
         }
     }   
    } 

    Shape& move_up(int i) { return operator[](i).move(0, 70); }
private:
    Point upperLeft;
    int gridSideX;
    int gridSideY;
    int gridRowNumber;
    int gridColumnNumber;
};
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>
#include "Graph.h"
#include "Simple_window.h"
#include "Group.h"

int main(){
    // define a window 
    Point tl(x_max()/2,0);
    int width = 700;
    int height = 700;
    string label = "class Group";
    Simple_window sw(tl, width, height, label);

    // instantiate a class Group object  
    Group gr();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < gr.size(); ++i) sw.attach(gr[i]);
    sw.wait_for_button();
}
```

Currently the wrapping function is getting underlined in red, when hover above it displays the following message:

> `Error: initial value to reference to non-const must be an lvalue`

The problem is that I can't find a  right way of accessing and modifying the elements in the vector of the base class, thus the following question:

What am I doing wrong? How to correctly implement the `Shape& move_up(int index);` function?

---

<sup>1. Apply the function `move();` that changes the coordinates of a `Shape` element of the vector.</sup>

<sup>2. All the additional files for compilation could be found: [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/Graphics/) and [here](http://www.fltk.org/index.php).</sup>

Comment: Does this really have anything to do with overloading `operator[]`, or with inheritance, or with templates? What does `.move()` return? If it's not a reference, the return value for `move_up` cannot be bound. Present a [minimal testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (and, please, I shouldn't have to prompt you to do this every time I see one of your questions)

Comment: It seems like `Group` inheriting from `MyVector<Shape>` is in violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: @TartanLlama Just read the principle; the class would  probably be implemented with  `MyVector<Shape>`  as data member.

Comment: @simplicisveritatis exactly. That would solve your issue as a side-effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `move_up()` has to:

- modify `Shape`'s coordinate
- return `Shape&` such that it could be `attache()`d to the window object, and its new location displayed on the screen.

To do that it just needs to be separated into two lines, where the first line modifies the `Shape` object and the second line returns it by reference:

```
Shape& move_up(int i) {
    operator[](i).move(0, 70); 
    return operator[](i);
}
```

or as suggested by *molbdnilo*:

```
Shape& move_up(int i) {
    auto& el = (*this)[i];
    el.move(0, 70); 
    return el;
}
```

Comment: Or `(*this)[i]`, which is less noisy.

Answer (score 2):

Your function `move()` returns `void`:

```
virtual void move(int dx, int dy);
```

What do you expect then when you try to have your `move_up()` return the *result* of `move()`:

```
return <something>.move(0, 70);
```

especially that you previously told the compiler that `move_up()` shall returns `Shape&`?